# ag-grid infinite scroll pagination does not work / angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

on the initial load of the component, all data is displayed as intended. But when switched to the next page, the grid clears and following error is displayed on the console:

> ERROR Error: ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle 
>   of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

Without the valueGetter in the devices column, the pagination works, but I need it to alter the devices array which comes from the service.

I tried it also with an cellRenderer, but the problem is, the content is not updated upon pagination and is always empty on the following pages.

Here's the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { SensorsListService } from "../services/sensors-list.service";
import { Sensor } from "src/app/shared/models/sensor.model";
import { IDatasource, IGetRowsParams } from "ag-grid-community";

@Component({
  selector: "app-sensors-list",
  templateUrl: "./sensors-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./sensors-list.component.scss"]
})
export class SensorsListComponent implements OnInit {
  sensorsList: Sensor[];
  frameworkComponents: any;
  columnDefs: any;
  rowData: any;
  gridApi: any;
  gridColumnApi: any;

  constructor(
    private sensorsListService: SensorsListService,
  ) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Field ID",
        field: "fieldId",
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
        width: 100
      },
      {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name",
        sortable: true,
        filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
        autoHeight: true,
        width: 300
      },
      {
        headerName: "Device",
        valueGetter: function(params) {
          const devices = [];
          if (params.data.devices.length) {
            params.data.devices.forEach(device => {
              devices.push(device.commNr);
            });
          }
          return devices;
        },
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
        width: 300
      }
    ];
  }

  dataSource: IDatasource = {
    getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
      const page = params.startRow / (params.endRow - params.startRow);

      if (Object.keys(params.filterModel).length) {
        this.sensorsListService
          .getFilteredSensorList(params.filterModel.name.filter)
          .subscribe(response => {
            params.successCallback(
              response.body.content,
              response.body.totalElements
            );
          });
      } else {
        this.sensorsListService.getAllSensors(page).subscribe(response => {
          params.successCallback(
            response.body.content,
            response.body.totalElements
          );
        });
      }
    }
  };

  ngOnInit() {}

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridApi.setDatasource(this.dataSource);
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
}
```

Comment: did you set the rowModelType  to 'infinite' as under your grid options ?

Comment: yes, the modeltype is set to infinite on the options

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is valueGetter, it does not work with infinite scroll unless you check undefined in params. For solution check this [aggrid server side paging 'cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716050/aggrid-server-side-paging-cannot-get-grid-to-draw-rows-when-it-is-in-the-middle)